# "no-cache" ​vs "max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, rfc2616

What's the​ difference between a HTTP response with `Cache-Control: no-cache` vs `Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate`?

Do browsers treat that as *identical*?

Comment: Semantically; not much. It's shorter, though.

Comment: @MarkNottingham. Does this hold in the *real world* too? Do browsers really treat them as *identical*?

Comment: I haven't tested in a while, but I believe so.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between Cache-Control: max-age=0 and no-cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1046966/1331430)

Answer (score 3):

In general different Browsers do not behave exactly the same wrt. HTTP cache headers.

One small difference I remember (can't find the source, so I'm not 100% this is the exact behavior description) is that Chrome (afair) treat `max-age=0` as if you specified `max-age=10` (assuming the behavior difference is small enough, but performance impact is still meaningful).

In any case, here are some other examples of HTTP cache behavior difference between browsers:

- Some will give preference to HTTP 1.0 Cache header (`Pragma`), others will give preference to HTTP 1.1 Cache headers
- Some Browsers (FF + ?) [don't honor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209514/firefox-no-cache-not-honored) `no-store` directive and store data in encrypted cache
- Some browsers ignore `no-cache` directive is specified after `public`, others don't.
- [IE ignores](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/browser-cache-vary-broken/) `max-age` when `vary` is present.
- etc.

My overall recommendation would be to use both `Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate`, `pragma: no-cache` (HTTP 1.0) and `Expires: 0` in order to ensure all browsers do not cache the content with these headers.

Comment: How did you get the info that Chrome treat `max-age=0` as if we specified `max-age=10`?

Comment: I remember this, but I can't find the source. I'll update the answer with a reservation until I find a right source. In any case: I can bring a number of more examples of browsers not behaving the same wrt. HTTP cache headers.